# What does "as due to one's actions" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage

While trying to get the meaning of the phrase "[come off worse](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/come+off+worse)" from Free dictionary, I bumped into this interpretation:

> To be viewed even more unfavorably in a negative situation, **as due to one's actions**.

I don't understand "*as due to*" here. I feel "*due to one's actions*" might be fairly good. What does the phrase "*as due to*" convey exactly?

Comment: *as* should be left out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wow, that Free Dictionary is worth every penny you paid for it.

First, the whole clause is unnecessary, since "come off worse" carries no implication about the cause.

And yes, "due to one's actions" would make more sense (but still be factually wrong).